# How to get image format when i get image via http request using nodejs

Tags: node.js, line-api

I'm getting image via line api. when user send image to my bot, I will get it, and upload to aws s3 bucket: `GET https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/{messageId}/content`

I got success image. I'm using `file = fs.createWriteStream("file.jpg")` and `pipe(file)`. However, it will be fixed at file extension "jpg". For example, the file I get has the extension "gif", it will still save in the format "jpg".

So, how to get image format, if I know image format, i can use fs.createWriteStream to create file have the same format.

Comment: you want image format before uploading to s3 or after?

Comment: I want before uploading to s3

Answer (score 0):

You can simply first read headers of image and you will get image format in it, according to image format can save it to `s3` Bucket.

Here is the sample code.

```
request.head('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png', function (err, res, body) {
    console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
    console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);
    let filename = 'image.png' // according to content type
    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
});
```

`filename` can be decided according to `content-type`